# Adhoc ports unavailable

Tags: networking, ssh, wireless, dhcp

I have created an adhoc network on wlan0 for my RPi using isc-dhcp-server to assign ips. This seems to work and I can connect from ubuntu and ping my RPi, however i can not SSH or access my remote i2p page (port 7657). It gives a connection refused on port 22. Any tips?

Below is my dhcpd.conf settings for isc-dhcp-server

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
option domain-name "RPi-network";
option routers 10.0.0.1; #default gateway

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.20; #IP range to offer
}

#static IP-assignment
host myLaptop {
    hardware ethernet My:ma:c:is:he:re:;
    fixed-address 10.0.0.100;
}
```

Comment: *"It is as if it has a firewall up"* -> A firewall will produce one of two results: A time out if it drops packets (this is only the case if you can actually ping the IP, otherwise it is timing out because there is no such address), or more commonly, a "prohibited" ICMP packet, which the application should report as blah blah prohibited.  If you receive *"connection refused"*, it is **not** a firewall, it is that there's no server running on that port.  You need to be more specific about your issue.  Try use `-v` or `-vv` with `ssh` when you connect, and edit in the output.